# How to optimize a php code for magento product info collection by product id to load fast

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, api

I am creating an API file for android to get product info by requesting with a product id in how to fast the loading process of that page

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard way to load product collection

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Thanks but  i am asking about optimizing the php code to load faster

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to load all the datas of the product, you can use :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('eq'=> $productID))
          ->addAttributeToSelect($listOfAttributes)
          ->setPageSize(1)
          ->getFirstItem();
```

where `$listOfAttributes` is an array of the attributes you want to retrieve. For example :   `$listOfAttributes = array('name','sku')`.